# Linear constraint with a floor function in Gurobi

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am building an MILP constraint system. Following is the constraint I need to build.

```
floor(a-b) <= 2c - 1
```

Here, a and b are real-valued. c is integer variable. I need the floor function to be able to assign appropriate values to the variables. How do I add this constraint in Gurobi? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I might be missing something, but would it not be sufficient to require that `a - b <= 2c`?

Comment: No, the problem is, I need `c` to be assigned `1` if `a>=b`. Otherwise assigned `0`

Answer (score 2):

Assume that a is bounded by the constant MaxA and similarilily let b <= MaxB.
Then, use the inequalities

(1): a <  b + c*MaxA

(2): b <= a + (1-c)*MaxB.

Let a>=b, thus (1) implies c=1, and (2) is trivially satisfied, independent on c. Otherwise, 
assume a is less than b , now (2) implies c=0 and (1) becomes trivial. (You should skip (2), if you just want to assure that a>=b implies c=1, and do not care for c otherwise.)